# How to sort a dictionary of two lists by value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am beginning Python and I have read so many posts trying to figure this out. I have a dictionary made up of two lists. One of these is made up of integers and the other is a list of letters. The dictionary is sorted alphabetically however I want it to be sorted by the values associated with each letter. These values are not full integers. Could someone please let me in laymans terms how I can do this.

This is the dictionary

```
{
 'A': '0.03',
 'C': '0.02',
 'D': '0.04',
 'E': '0.06',
 'F': '0.05',
 'G': '0.03',
 'H': '0.03',
 'I': '0.08',
 'K': '0.07',
 'L': '0.14',
 'M': '0.02',
 'N': '0.06',
 'P': '0.03',
 'Q': '0.04',
 'R': '0.03',
 'S': '0.11',
 'T': '0.05',
 'V': '0.05',
 'W': '0.02',
 'Y': '0.03'
}
```

I would really appreciate a workaround that does not use any packages.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to sort a dictionary at all? This makes only sense under rare circumstances.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, please [edit] to add what posts you've already read, what you've tried, and what hasn't worked. I'm also confused cause you mention lists and integers, but your data doesn't have either. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thanks wjandrea, it was good to check out the sites you recommended, another user provided a very good answer also, I was having difficulty using the sort function and making the key = lambda x, I wasn't sure how to approach it. Thanks for your help, I've bookmarked your links in case I have any more problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way
supposing you stored your dictionary in variable data

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

it outputs this

```
{'C': '0.02',
 'M': '0.02',
 'W': '0.02',
 'A': '0.03',
 'G': '0.03',
 'H': '0.03',
 'P': '0.03',
 'R': '0.03',
 'Y': '0.03',
 'D': '0.04',
 'Q': '0.04',
 'F': '0.05',
 'T': '0.05',
 'V': '0.05',
 'E': '0.06',
 'N': '0.06',
 'K': '0.07',
 'I': '0.08',
 'S': '0.11',
 'L': '0.14'}
```

Comment: Note that this requires Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6. Reference: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/4518341)

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly, I had looked at the sorted function, but I kept getting errors that it couldn't deal with non-integers etc... I couldn't figure out how to apply it properly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `sorted()` with a `lambda` for this task and simply convert back to `dict`, without using a list comprehension to iterate over keys and values again. -

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

```
{'C': '0.02',
 'M': '0.02',
 'W': '0.02',
 'A': '0.03',
 'G': '0.03',
 'H': '0.03',
 'P': '0.03',
 'R': '0.03',
 'Y': '0.03',
 'D': '0.04',
 'Q': '0.04',
 'F': '0.05',
 'T': '0.05',
 'V': '0.05',
 'E': '0.06',
 'N': '0.06',
 'K': '0.07',
 'I': '0.08',
 'S': '0.11',
 'L': '0.14'}
```

Incase you want it in descending order then -

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

Comment: Note that this requires Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6. Reference: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/4518341)

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {'A': '0.03', 'C': '0.02', 'D': '0.04', 'E': '0.06', 'F': '0.05', 'G': '0.03', 'H': '0.03', 'I': '0.08', 'K': '0.07', 'L': '0.14', 'M': '0.02', 'N': '0.06', 'P': '0.03', 'Q': '0.04', 'R': '0.03', 'S': '0.11', 'T': '0.05', 'V': '0.05', 'W': '0.02', 'Y': '0.03'}

def func(item):
    return item[1]

print( { k:v for k,v in sorted( d.items() , key= func ) } )
```

The `key` parameter of the sorted function takes a callback function which can be a lambda function or a regular callback function.